# Is it OK to have multiple docker-compose services using the same image like this?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few services running within a docker-compose file, such as 2 nginx services and 2 node services that share the same image.

I have noticed (increasingly more often) that when attempting to exec into one of those containers that share an image, I get the following error...

```
$ docker exec -it node_one bash 
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory`
```

I could be completely off the mark, but could this be being caused by the fact that they share an image and/or volume?

I was of the understanding that each container will essentially create a new (completely separate) instance of that image to run each container. Is that right or wrong?

Could the `working_dir` property be causing this? Any and all pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**Example**

```
version: '3'

services:
  node_one:
    image: node:latest
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/src/app:/var/www/src

  node_two:
    image: node:latest
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/src/app:/var/www/src

  nginx_one:
    image: nginx:latest
    working_dir: /etc/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/src/app:/var/www/src

  nginx_two:
    image: nginx:latest
    working_dir: /etc/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/src/app:/var/www/src
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with running multiple containers from the same image.  (Typical use would be to create a custom image `FROM node` and copy your application code in.)  Do you have a reproducible sequence of commands that causes this?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for replying. I don't yet no... it's seemingly random. I'm sure it's me configuring something correctly somewhere. When I get to the bottom of it, I'll post an answer.